# Can "never" be put inside an infinitive ("to never do")

Tags: negation, infinitives, grammar-myths

> "George vows **never to buy** Elaine lunch again."

I have two questions:

1. ***never** to do* — Is it proper grammar? I know I can say *not to do*.
2. *to **never** do* — Since the 60's the popularity of this structure is [rapidly increasing](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to%20never%20do&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,to%20never%20do;,c0). What confuses me is that *never* is put between *to* and *verb*, when *to verb* is the rigid infinitive construction.

Comment: There's nothing rigid about infinitive constructions.  There is no rule against "splitting infinitives" in English.

Comment: I am astonished (and gratified) that it has taken thirteen months for this question to be raised here. On ELU it took three weeks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both are correct; you can choose which sounds better in the sentence - "never to do" may allow more emphasis on never (IMO), but "to never do" is probably more common.

To answer your questions directly:

1. 'Never to do' is grammatically sound.
2. 'To never do' is also grammatically sound. Splitting infinitives is fine.

Comment: According to https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=never+to+do%2C+to+never+do&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnever%20to%20do%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20never%20do%3B%2Cc0, today *never to do* is 10 times more popular than *to never do* in writing. Forty years ago it was 100 times more popular.

Comment: Very interesting. In spoken English, I _suspect_ 'to never do' is more common. Many people try to avoid splitting infinitives in writing, and you can choose to also, but there is no rule against it (in English), as snailplane rightly comments.

Comment: Further reading: http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/~gpullum/grammar/splitinf.html